# Regex to match just the spaces only with in doublequotes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

**How to match only the spaces(not the strings) that is within double quotes and rest of the spaces must be ignored**  , the following regex **\s(?=\")** will select the only the space which is before a double quote so i was thinking there would be some sort of regex to match the space only with in double quotes

Comment: Have you done something?

Comment: i beg your pardon for being ignorant do pls enlighten me, the following regex \s(?=\") will select the only the space which is before a double quote so i was thinking there would be some sort of regex to match the space only with in double quotes so posted this question but i dont know why this question calls for a down vote :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would matches the spaces which are present inside the double quotes,

```
\s(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vW2pQ7/2)